# Open Webview on TouchableOpacity onPress React-Native

Tags: webview, react-native

Presently I am using Linking but it is opening the url outside the app, I want this app to be opened within the app without showing the URL.

But unable to open Webview on TouchableOpecity onPress event in React-Native. Do I need to add a page and then open the page with URL ?

Can anyone please help.

Comment: I want to Open the URL within app by mistake had written "I want this app to be opened within the app"

Answer (score 1):

I am considering the simplest of cases where i am rendering a single component and no navigator is being used.

```
class ABC extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
   check : false
  }
 }
 renderWebView(){
   if(this.state.check){
     return(
       <WebView
          source={{uri: 'your url goes here'}}
          style={{marginTop: 20}}
       />
     );
   }else {
      return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>this.setState({check: true})}>
           <Text>Open WebView</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
     );
   }
 }
 render() {
   return (
     <View style={{flex:1}}>
      {this.renderWebView()}
     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

You can use one of the Navigators and treat the webview component as one route.